# How to use django-meta module(or any easier way) to render html meta tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've tried to follow the [Django-meta](https://django-meta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html) documentation to the best of my ability. 
Added it to my list of applications in the settings file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'meta',
]
```

my model looks like

```
from django.db import models
from meta.models import ModelMeta

class Article(ModelMeta, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


    _metadata = {
        'title': 'title',
        'description': 'content',
    }
```

My views.py looks like

```
def article_detail_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    template_name = ['snmov/home.html']
    context = {}
    context['object'] = obj
    context['meta'] = obj.as_meta()
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

The path to this view looks like

```
path('<str:slug>/', article_detail_view, name='article_detail'),
```

The home.html extends a base.html whose head tag has

```
{% include "meta/meta.html" %}
```

meta.html has

```
{{meta}}
```

**My Problem:**
I want it to render the 'title' and 'content' of the article in the meta tag, but it renders the meta tag as
`<meta.views.Meta object at ******>`
on the body of the page.

**Questions:**
How can I make it render in the head of the document?
What am I missing in order to make the meta tag render like it's supposed to?

Any help would be really appreciated. I can provide more information if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an block in the header of your base template:

```
<head>
     ...
     ...

     {% block meta_extend %}
     {% endblock %}
</head>
```

Than you can print your meta tags in your template:

```
{% block meta_extend %}
    {{ meta }}
{% endblock %}
```

or something like that:

```
{% block meta_extend %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ obj.description }}">
    <meta name="title" content="{{ obj.title }}">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but what worked was
```{% block meta_extend %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ meta.description }}">
    <meta name="title" content="{{ meta.title }}">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, this if statement is supposed to change the meta tags according to the url loaded. Nothing shows when the 'homepage' loads, but the desired meta tags loads up on other pages.

Do you have an idea why?
```{% url 'homepage' as home %}
{% if request.get_full_path == home %}
    <title>Foo Bar Title </title>
    <meta name="description" content="Foo bar Content">
{% else %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ meta.description }}">
    <meta name="title" content="{{ meta.title }}"> 
{% endif %}```

Comment: Is this block in your base or in your detailed article template?
You can write an default in the `block` statement into your base template, like: `{% block meta_extend %}<title>Foo Bar Title </title> <meta name="description" content="Foo bar Content">{% endblock %}`

Comment: It's in the detailed article template. But this solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The package information/documentation is pretty scarce.

What I noticed is that :

1. Reducing the Social Network to "1" at a time, helps me simplifying the content of the Console's errors
2. It seems that several variables prefer to be set via the "settings" (config file), rather than setting them in the code.
       META_SITE_PROTOCOL = 'https'
       META_SITE_DOMAIN = env('DJANGO_META_SITE_DOMAIN', default='www.InternationalExampleNetwork.com')
       # META_USE_SITES = True  # WARNING : DO NOT ACTIVATE as it makes the compilation fail.

   ```
   META_USE_OG_PROPERTIES = True        
   FB_TYPE=''        
   FB_APPID=''
   FB_PROFILE_ID='1111111'        
   FB_PUBLISHER='@InternationalExampleNetwork'
   FB_AUTHOR_URL='/en/'
   FB_PAGES=''

   META_USE_TWITTER_PROPERTIES = False
   TWITTER_TYPE=11
   TWITTER_SITE=env('DJANGO_META_SITE_DOMAIN', default='www.InternationalExampleNetwork.com')
   TWITTER_AUTHOR='International Example Network'
   # Is there still some use for Google+ ... ? 
   META_USE_GOOGLEPLUS_PROPERTIES = False
   ```
3. So far for *ME* documentation in the OG site (https://ogp.me/) has been of little help (future will tell).